# Bundle install failed installing ffi (due to env command error?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, macos, installation, bundle

My bundle install failed installing ffi on my mac even though the ffi gem (with right version 1.0.11) has been installed just fine. I got the following error when running "bundle install":

```
 Installing ffi (1.0.11) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
... 
creating Makefile

make
Configuring libffi for i386
env: --disable-static: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Configuring libffi for x86_64
env: --disable-static: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** ["/mypath/clients/myapp/rails=2.3.5/ruby/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2
An error occured while installing ffi (1.0.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried

```
gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'
```

which went through just fine. 
Then I look into the failing Makefile and ran

```
make -n
```

to see what happened. It turned out that the make failed on the command:

```
 cd "/mypath/clients/myapp/rails=2.3.5/ruby/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c"/libffi-$arch && env CC=" gcc" CFLAGS="-arch $arch " LDFLAGS="-arch $arch" "/mypath/clients/myapp/rails=2.3.5/ruby/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/configure --disable-static --with-pic=yes --disable-dependency-tracking --host=$arch-apple-darwin > /dev/null;
```

To be specific, it failed on

```
env CC=" gcc" CFLAGS="-arch $arch " LDFLAGS="-arch $arch" "/mypath/clients/myapp/rails=2.3.5/ruby/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/configure --disable-static --with-pic=yes --disable-dependency-tracking --host=$arch-apple-darwin > /dev/null;
```

Apparently the env command thinks the part

```
"/mypath/clients/myapp/rails=2.3.5/ruby/1.8/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/configure
```

is to set an environment variable since the path contains "=". If I manually change "=" to "_", the env command works just fine. However, this path was automatically generated by "bundle install", and it has been working in the past.

I just tried

```
 bundle install --path=rails_2.3.5
```

and it went through. But I still wonder how the path rails=2.3.5 worked in the past.

Was that because I accidentally changed some settings on my mac? Can I make env recognize that "=" in quotes are not for environment variables?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem and at that time I cleaned my all gem which was installed and than again doing bundle and it was working.

I am not sure if it will work for you or not but still you can try.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem(Mac OS X Lion).
In my case, after upgrading to Mac OS X Lion, I had lost my gcc command line tools.

This is how to install Command Line Tools;
1.Install Xcode 4
2.Xcode -> preferences -> Downloads tab -> Command Line Tools

After installing, my case solved.

Comment: Additionally you may need to install/reinstall https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer. My installation was broken after upgrade to Mountain Lion. Reinstall osx-gcc fixed roblem with ffi.